# FFMPEG / streameye - MJPEG streaming from raspebbry cam

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, rtmp, avconv

I'm trying to stream video from different Raspberry Pi's ..; RPI 2B /2 B+ and RPI 3.
I found out how to stream rtmp / flv video through NINGX and it works fine but now I need to convert this stream to MJPEG stream. Actually I need it as input for motion (detection)

I've tried mjeg_streamer to publish a MJPEG stream using FFMPEG / image2  in front to split the stream into image chunhs. But it's too slow and to much greedy

after many searches I've installed streameye which seems perfect. but the process traps 10s after a web client connects to the server hosted on the raspberry py (2/3 same result so not an ARM61/71 issue I think .. same with FFMPEG or AVCONV).

... and  more over it crashes the ssh session we are connected to access the rapsberry device. An FFMPEG trap generating a SSH session issue ?. 
Note that the raspberry was not down after connection loss as all it's services were still up and running. Just need to connect via SSH to again.

I don't know if it's due to my ffmpeg feeding command or if it's a streameye nug. Didn't find any info about on google  but a web client issue that would have been fixed in 0.8 (the version I'm working on)

from a FLV / h264 I run

```
avconv -r 15 -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/app/my_stream -c:v mjpeg  -crf 15 -f mjpeg  - | streameye -p 8080
```

the source stream is defined as follow (no audio stream) :

```
Input #0, live_flv, from 'rtmp://boxnet-0-eth/live/boxnet-2':
Metadata:
Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
displayWidth    : 480
displayHeight   : 320
fps             : 0
profile         : 
level           : 
Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 480x320, 1k tbr, 1k tbn
```